# How to remove files that start with a number and don't end with a letter?

Tags: unix

I am doing some practice question off a text book and I ran into one thing that I cannot seem to solve. It wants us to remove all files that

- start with a number and
- end is not a letter

So I use Linux and created a few empty files like this:

```
>1afsd.
>12fdfd
>12dfad
>23fdfa1
>fdafad!
```

I tried with this command

```
rm -i [0-9]
```

which only removes the ones that have number in it

```
rm -i *[!a-zA-Z]
```

which only remove the one that does not have a letter at the end.

Is there a way for it to do both? I tried

```
rm -i [0-9]* *[!a-zA-Z]
```

but it's just the same command ran twice. How do I combine them?

Note: I am using the  -i so I don't delete the file or I have to recreate them every time.

Comment: why not `rm [0-9]*[!a-zA-Z]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
rm -i [0-9]*[!a-zA-Z]
```

should work.

Comment: ah so the * symbol remove everything in between?

Comment: @ricedragon the * symbol matches any character.  Check this out for some more in depth info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29

Comment: The `*` symbol matches zero or more occurrences of any characters.